# PHP list created using While loop - How update all using submit button

Tags: php, mysql, list, datatable

Happy Evening All,

Group submission has been executed without collecting the First name and Last name we would like to collect Firstname and Lastname,  re-posting to the group user to enter First name and Last name.

Here below is the code used to list the group information with INPUT field to collect the First name and Last name.

Any Idea on how to post all the Input data of the first name and last name into DB in one submit button.

Any help would be grateful.

```
 $Group_ID = '22125';

mysql_connect('localhost','root','') or die (mysql_error ()); 
mysql_select_db("GroupDB") or die (mysql_error ()); 

$strSQL = "SELECT ID, firstname, lastname from people where pay_orderid ='$Group_ID'";
mysql_query($strSQL) or die (mysql_error()); 
$query = mysql_query($strSQL);

echo "<table class='table-responsive'><thead><tr><th>First Name</th><th>Last Name</th></tr></thead><tbody>";

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
$CurID= $row['ID']; 
$firstname= $row['firstname']; 
$lastname = $row['lastname'];
echo "<tr><td>".$Group_ID."</td><td>".$CurID."</td><td><input value='".$firstname."'></td><td><input value='".$lastname."'></td></tr>";
}

echo "</tbody></table>";?>
```

Comment: Surround everything with <form>...</form>.

Comment: You are missing name attribute for input tag. You also have to declare a form.

Comment: What you're looking for is called a "form".  Any PHP tutorial should include the use of one.

Comment: Sure will add a form; adding form field will update only ONE field value related to one ID - my question is how to add value to Mulitple row fields in submission? hope this is clear

Comment: You need to name input fields differently, so it shouldn't be only <input name="firstName" value="$firstname"> but something like: <input name="firstName1" value....   This tutorial https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/php/wish-list-lesson7.html could give you some pointers.

Comment: Off-topic English tip: you should say *"I would be grateful for any help"* or *"Any help would be appreciated"* because "grateful" should refer to the person receiving the help, and not the help itself, so technically *"Any help would be grateful"* is wrong, but your sentiment is still clearly expressed. Meta-topic: those types of statements are considered noise anyway on SE

Comment: @Dolfa you can use an array for input names such as `input name="firstname[]"`

Comment: @Jeff Puckett: I wondered that there was better way how to handle input fields, building mysql insert query with these arrays would be much simpler. Thanks for reminding me.

Comment: ` if (isset($_POST['updateDBname']))
{ 
 echo "updating db";
 $pdo = new PDO ("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=GroupDB","root",""); 
 
foreach($_POST['firstname'] as $row=>$first_name)
{
 $up_firstname = mysql_real_escape_string($first_name); 
    $up_lastname= mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['lastname'][$row]);
  
    $involv = "INSERT INTO people(firstname, lastname)
               VALUES('$up_firstname', '$up_lastname')";

    mysql_query($involv);
}
 
}` **Trying to use the above code** NO LUCK - I would be grateful for any help

Comment: it is creating new data, how to Map these data to the corresponding ID...

Comment: MYSQL insert is the issue - Solved by Update - thanking everyone for sharing your thoughts.

Answer (score 0):

Working Solution: add `name` to the `input` field with `[]` example.

```
<td><input name= "firstname[]"  value='".$firstname."'></td>


foreach($_POST['firstname'] as $row=>$fname)
{    
$up_firstname = mysql_real_escape_string($fname); 
$up_CurID= mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['CurID'][$row]);
$up_lastname= mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['lastname'][$row]);

$involv = "UPDATE `people` SET `firstname` = '$up_firstname', `lastname` = '$up_lastname'  WHERE `people`.`ID` = '$up_CurID';"; 
mysql_query($involv);
```